# How can I compare objects from one scene against objects from other scene/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It might be slowly or take long if I have for example over 10000 objects since each object should be compared against all the others if I'm not mistaken.

Why ? In my game I did some changes on one big object children it have a lot of children. I can't remember what the changes I did on what objects. But I don't want also just to copy the original objects from the original scene and overwrite the others with the changes since some of the changes I want to keep.

There are changes I did and know and want to keep and there are changes I did and not sure where and when and those I might want to remove later.

The main goal is to get a nice output log or to a text file something that will tell how many objects the same how many not and each objects that are not the same have same name but not same rotation scaling position or components to tell me what are the changes difference.

My first scene is contains the objects with the changes. The second scene contains the original objects before the changes.

This script is attached to empty gameobject in my first scene :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CompareObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mainGame;
    public string numberOfObjects;
    public string comparisonObjects;
    public float waitTime;
    public List<GameObject> allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool compareAtStart = false;
    public bool pauseGameOnComparison = false;

    private Coroutine comparer;

    private void Start()
    {
        allobjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>().ToList();

        numberOfObjects = allobjects.Count.ToString();

        if (compareAtStart == true)
        {
            StartComparing();
        }
    }

    public void StartComparing()
    {
        if (pauseGameOnComparison == true)
        {
           mainGame.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            comparer = StartCoroutine(Compare());
        }
    }

    public void StopComparing()
    {
        if (comparer != null)
        {
            comparisonObjects = "";
            allobjects = new List<GameObject>();
            StopCoroutine(comparer);
            mainGame.SetActive(true);

            comparer = null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Compare()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (allobjects.Count == 0)
            {
                StopComparing();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (GameObject go in allobjects)
                {
                    if (go.name != "Game Manager")
                    {
                        Searcher.PrintSearch(go.name);
                    }

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my first scene I moved all the objects under Main Game to easy be able to make the comparison/s if the game is keep running or on pause.

The second class code should make the comparison it self :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class Searcher
{
    [MenuItem("Tools/PrintSearch")]
    public static void PrintSearch(string objectName)
    {
        var componentType = typeof(BoxCollider);

        var scenes = Enumerable.Range(0, SceneManager.sceneCount)
            .Select(SceneManager.GetSceneAt)
            .ToArray();
        var objectsWithNames = scenes
            .ToDictionary(s => s, s => GetSceneObjectsWithName(s, objectName.ToLower()));

        var forLog = objectsWithNames
            .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Select(child =>
                $"Scene {pair.Key.name}: object name '{child.gameObject.name}' {(child.GetComponent(componentType) != null ? "contains" : "do not contains")} component {componentType.Name}"));

        Debug.Log(string.Join("\n", forLog));
    }

    private static Transform[] GetSceneObjectsWithName(Scene scene, string objectName)
    {
        return scene.GetRootGameObjects()
            .SelectMany(g => GetChildHierarchyRecursively(g.transform))
            .Where(t => t.gameObject.name.ToLower().Contains(objectName))
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Transform> GetChildHierarchyRecursively(Transform parentTransform)
    {
        yield return parentTransform;
        if (parentTransform.childCount > 0)
            yield return parentTransform;
    }
}
```

The first problem is I see in the console in the log this :

Method Searcher.PrintSearch has invalid parameters. MenuCommand is the only optional supported parameter.
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

And it's writing to log all the time :

UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

The second problem is that I'm not sure if I'm doing it at all the right way with the CompareObjects script.

Comment: Oof. Good luck man, this isn't going to be easy, no mate how you slice it. All I can suggest is that in the future you use some kind of source repository. Even then, Unit scene files aren't easy to merge changes with; Unity built their collabs thing, which is supposed to handle it nicer than Source Tree, but I've not used it.

Comment: Totally agree with Draco18s .. this looks like an XY problem that should be rather solved using version control. Additionally you could consider making it a prefab next time => Unity can then keep track of any changes in the scene instance against the original prefab and you can decide which ones to revert and which ones to apply to the prefab...